# I need help for a click action

Tags: python, click, screen-scraping

this is my first questionhere :)

I am looking to scrape a site and when accepting cookies I have a problem with my last line. Cookies I have a problem with my last line. I tried with CSS Selector / BY Class name ... But I can't find a solution. Could you help me? Thank you in advance!!!

---

my code :

```py
from    selenium                             import  webdriver
from    selenium.webdriver.common.by         import  By
import  time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe') 

keyword = "APPL"

driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/history?p="+ keyword)
driver.maximize_window()
try :
 cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "scroll-down-btn").click()
except :
 pass
time.sleep(1)
accept = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"btn secondary reject-all").click()
```

---

And here is the code of the button on which I try to click

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn secondary accept-all consent_reject_all_2" name="agree" value="agree">Accepter tout</button>
```

I am looking to scrape a site and when accepting cookies I have a problem with my last line. Cookies I have a problem with my last line. I tried with CSS Selector / BY Class name ... But I can't find a solution. Could you help me? Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: please reformat your code

Comment: yes @XiaominWu, marcel h helped me put the code better for my quesion request:)

Answer (score 0):

select by XPATH should work in your case

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

keyword = "APPL"

driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/history?p=" + keyword)
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    cookie = driver.find_element(By.ID, "scroll-down-btn").click()
except:
    pass

time.sleep(1)

# Find the button using XPath and click it
accept_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn secondary accept-all consent_reject_all_2']")
accept_button.click()
```